# $setValidity() breaking ng-model when trying to confirm a password

Tags: angularjs

I am trying enforce "confirm password" in an Angular form

```
<input
     type="password" name="password"
     ng-model="regFormData.password" ng-change="dupCheck(regForm.password,regForm.repassword)" required=""/>
<input
     type="password" name="repassword"
     ng-model="regFormData.repassword" ng-change="dupCheck(regForm.password,regForm.repassword)"/>
```

The problem is that `dupCheck()` looks like this

```
  $scope.dupCheck = function(p1, p2) {
    p2.$setValidity("mismatch",  (p1.$viewValue === p2.$viewValue));
  };
```

The first time `$setValidity()` is called is the first time that password or repassword is changed, which means that the two fields are different and the second argument therefore `false`.  Eventually, of course, it set to `true`, but it is too late and repassword is broken: it will not copy its value into its model.

Two questions:

1. What is wrong here?  Is this a known bug?  Am I misusing `$setValidity()`?
2. The whole set-up seems rather elaborate.  Is there a simpler way to enforce equality like this?

Answer (score 0):

please, look for a solution with I had implemented last week:

```
app.directive('sameAs', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { other: '=sameAs' },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.sameAs = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                return viewValue === scope.other;
            };
            scope.$watch('other', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                ctrl.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

to use, please put same-as on second input:

```
<input type="password" ng-model="pass"/>
<input type="password" ng-model="pass2" same-as="pass"/>
```

observe the watch. It's necessary, because the user can fill the second field first, and then, confirm (or correct) on first field. Without this option, the second field could be stay invalid.